# Latex always attempts to align the beginning of a section of paragraph at the beginning of a new page

Tags: page-breaking

I am writing a paper using Usenix's template: https://www.usenix.org/sites/default/files/usenix2019_v3.1.tex

I have noticed that this template attempts to put the beginning of a new section or a new paragraph to the next new page as much as possible, by stretching the space between sections, paragraphs, and images, in the previous page.

While this could be a nice feature and making the paper looks nicer, it is not helpful as the paper has a page limit and I want to pack as much content as possible. I wonder if there is a way to tell the template relax and not always try to make such adjustment?

Comment: Try `\raggedbottom`

Comment: Thanks I have edited the content to fit the page. Interestingly, \raggedbottom does not work. The document will not stretch the space between sections, but will leave larger blank at the bottom of a column. In my case it does not shorten the overall length at all.